# How to Upgrade OpenCV to Specific Version Using Pip?

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I want to install OpenCV 3.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. I tried to build from source following tutorial on internet but run to this problem:

> ImportError:
>   /home/ivan/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.so:
>   undefined symbol: _ZTIN2cv3dnn19experimental_dnn_v35LayerE

So I decided to just upgrade OpenCV using `pip` following solution on github https://github.com/CharlesShang/FastMaskRCNN/issues/111:

```
pip3 install --upgrade opencv-python
```

It works fine, cv2 successfully imported. But it directly upgraded to `opencv 4.0.0` . Is there any way to upgrade opencv to specific version (ex: 3.4.0) using `pip`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you have to do is to put the version in the command as follows

```
pip3 install --upgrade opencv-python==3.4.0
```

Comment: Thank you, surprisingly simple. For addition `3.4.0` is not available so I have to input  `3.4.0.12` or `3.4.0.14`

Answer (score 0):

Actually (in 2020) Opencv library is version 4.2.XX
so my suggestion:

pip3 install --upgrade opencv-python==4.2.34

Comment: pip3 install --upgrade opencv-python==4.2.0.34 (you missed one zero)